Customization to allow for Sys Admins and Sales Managers (by Role) can edit Forecast Category
Can I create permissions based on roles for the forecast category? Or is it only by user?

Are you referring to Forecast Category related to Opportunity Stages? What do you mean when you say "Edit"? Edit the picklist values on the record, or edit/change the values available in the picklist?

Hey @morganmarchese This is essentially what Im trying to do: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385893&type=1 The problem im having is that I'm trying to do this in a flow builder since the process builder is going away. Can you help me understand this article but in 'flow builder' terms?
